# Code to avoid selenium stale element reference showing error in Eclipse editor

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am writing the following code to resolve stale element reference in selenium. However, in eclipse it is giving me error on: final  boolean retrying (By by)-this line.Also, first i wanted to use public boolean retrying(By by) instead of final boolean retrying (By by), but that was giving me error from the eclipse editor.

```
package com.TSOne.tcone;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class CalenderFfdriver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
   "/Users/owner/desktop/chromedriver");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get("http://www.path2usa.com/travel-companions");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#travel_date")).click();


    List<WebElement>dates =driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".day"));
    System.out.println(dates.size());

     final  boolean retrying (By by) {
        boolean result = false;
        int attempts = 0;
        while(attempts < 2) {
            try {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='datepicker- 
         switch']")).click();
                result = true;
                break;
            } catch(StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            }
            attempts++;
        }
        return;
    }

 WebElement navigator =driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(" 
 [class='datepicker-days'] th[class='next']"));

    while(!driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[class='datepicker-days'] 
    th[class='datepicker-switch']")).getText().contains("April")) 

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[class='datepicker-days'] 
    th[class='next']")).click();



    for(int i=0;i<dates.size();i++) {
         String text=dates.get(i).getText();
        if(text.equalsIgnoreCase("23"))

            dates.get(i).click();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can't define method inside `main`. Or inside any other method.

Comment: You have define "final  boolean retrying (By by)" method in main method, Which is not correct. you have to define it outside of main method, and call retrying method from main method.

Answer (score 0):

Define `final boolean retrying (By by)` method outside of your `main` method and it should work.

```
package ee.sims;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class CalederFfdriver {

private static WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
            "/Users/owner/desktop/chromedriver");


    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get("http://www.path2usa.com/travel-companions");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#travel_date")).click();


    List<WebElement>dates =driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".day"));
    System.out.println(dates.size());



    WebElement navigator =driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[class='datepicker-days'] th[class='next']"));

    while(!driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[class='datepicker-days'] th[class='datepicker-switch']")).getText().contains("April")) 

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[class='datepicker-days'] th[class='next']")).click();



    for(int i=0;i<dates.size();i++) {
        String text=dates.get(i).getText();
        if(text.equalsIgnoreCase("23"))

            dates.get(i).click();

    }
}
final  boolean retrying (By by) {
    boolean result = false;
    int attempts = 0;
    while(attempts < 2) {
        try {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='datepicker-switch']")).click();
            result = true;
            break;
        } catch(StaleElementReferenceException e) {
        }
        attempts++;
    }
    // note that i replaced "return;" here because it was a syntax error
    return result;
}
}
```

The code above has no compilation errors.

Comment: @Isgita,@Arthur-with everybody's suggestions, I edited my code and it is fine now (no compilation error). However, it is still throwing stale element error. Thank you all.